# Java multidimential array out of bounds

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexoutofboundsexception, sudoku

I have been trying to fill my

```
 int[][][] sudoku = new int[5][9][9];
```

array with

```
String[][] tmp = new String[21][21];
```

tmp[][] holds numbers like

```
005700020009600020 
490060010140050030
```

For example this code works perfect and it gives me the number I want

```
System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(tmp[4][10]));
```

But this code

```
//sudoku1
        b=0; c=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            for (int j = 9; j < 18; j++) {
                sudoku[1][b][c] = Integer.valueOf(tmp[i][j]);
            c++;
            }
            b++;
        }
```

throws "Index 9 out of bounds for length 9" error

Comment: Create and post your [mcve].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Comment: Yes @gmanjon helped me with the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have `c` defined outside both loops, and added 1 each execution in the inner loop. The inner loop gets executed 6*9 times, so `c` can reach even the value 54, but it throws exception when it reaches 9 when trying to use `sudoku[1][b][c]`, as the array indexes for the third element of the multiarray `sudoku` go from 0 to 8.

Comment: Yes, it solved my problem. I don't really understand how I couldn't see this. Thank you good sir!

Comment: You are most welcome. Don't worry, it happens to everyone. Once I spent half an hour wondering why my code didn't enter in my loop with `myVar == "S"`, when I knew for sure that the value of `myVar` was definately `"S"` xDDD